# Consuming web services with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, web-services

I am completely new to web services and I want to implement one. I did some research and I came across this site http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html. The thing is given here but I have no idea on how to consume this web service as a client.

Let's say I have a client file which is supposed to display the users.

How do i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm new to astrophysics and  i want to build me a space rocket

Comment: check out the sample code given that will direct you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample JSON Web-service code snippet for u to learn....
but you should have a basic knowledge b4 to dive in...!

for example below code is in **submit_user_details.php** 
you need to call the page for example 
*localhost/appname/webservices/submit_user_details.php*

```
<?php 
require_once('../Connections/db_connection.php');
?>
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json); 

$pin=$obj->{'pin'};
$name=$obj->{'name'};
$phone=$obj->{'phone'};
$second_number=$obj->{'second_number'};
$home_no=$obj->{'home_no'};
$email=$obj->{'email'};

//mysql_select_db($db, $db_connection)or die ('->>Error selecting database'.mysql_error()); 

$query = "UPDATE `haji_members` SET `name`= '".$name."',`phone`= '".$phone."',`secondary_phone`= '".$second_number."',`home_number`= '".$home_no."',`email`= '".$email."' WHERE pincode='".$pin."'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());  

    $posts = array();

    if($result != 1)
    {
        $post = array("message"=>"0");
        $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    }

    else{
        $post = array("message"=>"1");
        $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    }


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));

@mysql_close($db_connection);
?>
```

**The output would look like**

```
 {"posts":[{"post":{"tot_count":"0","username":null,"password":null}}]}
```